# Roman Numeral Switch Case not evaluating properly

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, bitwise-operators, roman-numerals

I am getting an unexpected result in a roman numeral conversion function. It will evaluate a 1, 2, or 4 digit number correctly. It will also correctly process the 3rd digit of a 4 digit number. If the number is 3 digits it evaluates the hundred's place like the one's place.

```
function convertToRoman(num) {

var evaluate = num.toString();
var replace = "";
var oneUnit;
var fiveUnit;
var tenUnit;


for (var i = 0; i < evaluate.length; i++ )
{

switch (evaluate.length | i)
  {
    case 1|0:
    case 2|1:
    case 3|2:
    case 4|3:
      oneUnit = "I";
      fiveUnit = "V";
      tenUnit = "X";
      break;
    case 2|0:
    case 3|1:
    case 4|2:
      oneUnit = "X";
      fiveUnit = "L";
      tenUnit = "C";
      break;
    case 3|0:
    case 4|1:
      oneUnit = "C";
      fiveUnit = "D";
      tenUnit = "M";
      break;
    case 4|0:
      oneUnit = "M";
      fiveUnit = "MMMMM";
      tenUnit = "MMMMMMMMMM";
      break;
  }


switch (evaluate.charAt(i))
{
  case "1":
  replace += oneUnit;
  break;

  case "2":
  replace += oneUnit + oneUnit;
  break;

  case "3":
  replace += oneUnit + oneUnit + oneUnit;
  break;

  case "4":
  replace += oneUnit + fiveUnit;
  break;

  case "5":
  replace += fiveUnit;
  break;

  case "6":
  replace += fiveUnit + oneUnit;
  break;

  case "7":
  replace += fiveUnit + oneUnit + oneUnit;
  break;

  case "8":
  replace += fiveUnit + oneUnit + oneUnit + oneUnit;
  break;

  case "9":
  replace += oneUnit + tenUnit;
  break;
}
}
num = replace;
return num;
}
```

Desired Return for 555: "DLV"
Return for 555: "VVV"

Desired Return for 1555: "MDLV"
Return for 1555: "MDLV"

Why are the first 2 digits of a 3 digit number not being assigned to the right case?

Comment: You appear to have some issues with the language syntax. Are you aware that you are using the bitwise OR operator (`|`), not the logical OR operator (`||`)?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that the case requires something like an "&&" in an if statement so that both statements have to be true. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: A switch statement can only evaluate one expression against its case values. You should convert the switch block into a series of if/else statements.

Comment: @user1421750 That did the trick. You want to put that as an answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: Alright, put it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match sets of values, but a switch statement can only evaluate one expression against its case values. The bitwise OR operator is misused here, because the result will not be a concatenation of the values of `evaluate.length` and `i`. You should convert the first switch block into a series of if/else statements.